# Is mathematics aprioristic?

Tags: geometry, soft-question, arithmetic, axioms, philosophy

Is mathematics aprioristic? I do not know. Some axioms of arithmetic and geometry arose clearly inspired by the observation of Nature. After that, those areas of mathematics were often developed with little to no regard to any "real world" implications. Look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relationship_between_mathematics_and_physics#Philosophical_problems) and [this.](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Vladimir_Arnold#Quotes)

Comment: Too broad to be answered... Of course, since ancient time to the present, the link between mathematics and "real world" is strong: from conunting and measuring as source for arithmetic and geometry, to the 20th Century development of tensor analysis for Relativity.

Comment: At the same time, there are many examples of math theories and disciplines developed in a pure abstract way (*a priori*) that subseqently found "practical" applications: prime number theory and criptography as wella s group theory and quantum mechanics.

Comment: I think that my question can be answered with "Yes." or "No." and then some justification (arguments, reasoning, past research, personal studies, etc...). Because of this I think that my question should be reopen.

Comment: NO; your question has a "philosophical" nature and very seldom philosophical questions have Y/N answer. The firs step to try to be more specific is to use the philosophical terminology in the most precise way that is possible. What do you mean with "aprioristic" ? The most reasonable meaning of [a priori](http://www.iep.utm.edu/apriori/) is : "can be known independent of any experience".

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA: Okay. You have convinced me. I agree with you, my question is not specific enough.

Comment: You can "move" your question to PSE, starting browsing the tag [philosophy-of-mathematics](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/philosophy-of-mathematics).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whatever the precise meaning of the term *aprioristic*, mathematics is no more aprioristic than the other exact sciences. Progress in mathematics takes place through increasing our understanding of phenomena that are usually classified under the rubric "mathematical" (though the term may not be entirely well-defined), and as in other exact sciences, ultimate and complete understanding is never reached but better scientific (e.g., mathematical) frameworks are developed that give better conceptual understanding of "mathematical" phenomena. This view is developed in more detail in [this 2012 publication in *Foundations of Science*](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s10699-011-9223-1) (see section 7 there).

Since few people would argue that chemistry and physics (for example) are aprioristic, I would argue the same for mathematics.

With regard to the quotes from Arnold in the link given: I believe Arnold's views concerning David Hilbert are too simplistic.

Comment: What are "exact sciences" ? Maybe sciences using mathematics ?

Comment: The two terms that are generally used are *natural sciences* and *exact sciences*.  The former is generally used to describe the sciences involved with the description/analysis/understanding of nature and does not cover mathematics itself, whereas the latter term is used to describe the sciences as contrasted with social sciences. I think any dictionary would tell you that. @MauroALLEGRANZA

Comment: So again: chemistry and physiscs are "exact" ? Why ? Because they use mathematics. The fact that they use it implies that math is "applicable" to the real world; this does not necessarily imply that math is not *a priori*.

Comment: What you are stating is a certain philosophical position, which is essentially what Gauss referred to when he called mathematics "the queen of the sciences". I think this is a rather idealistic position.  What you seem to be arguing essentially is that the validity of the sciences stems solely from their use of mathematics. This position could be arguable but I don't think all the scientists believe this. Perhaps Galileo did and I have great respect for Galileo, but philosophy has moved ahead since the 17th century.

Comment: [A priori](http://www.iep.utm.edu/apriori/): The terms "a priori" and "a posteriori" are used primarily to denote the foundations upon which a proposition is known. A given proposition is knowable a priori if it can be known independent of any experience other than the experience of learning the language in which the proposition is expressed, whereas a proposition that is knowable a posteriori is known on the basis of experience. "

Comment: Perhaps, but in this context the term is typically used to describe a certain formalistic attitude toward mathematics (which by the way was NOT Hilbert's by any means) and which I personally find rather naive.